# How can I predict if water will stick to the outside wall of a container when pouring at a certain angle?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

I want to predict if water will spill while pouring it from one container to another due to it sticking to the outside wall of the pouring container and running down through it.

I know the angle at which I'll pour the water, what other factors do I need to consider to predict if spilling will occur?

Comment: @JohnRennie Yeah, this seems to be duplicate, should I delete this question? Or let it be closed?

Comment: I'd leave your question here. It does no harm to have duplicates as it makes answers easier to find for people searching the site.